# JAXB: How can I unmarshal XML without namespaces

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<object>
   <str>the type</str>
   <bool type="boolean">true</bool>        
</object>
```

And I want to unmarshal it to an object of the class below

```
@XmlRootElement(name="object")
public class Spec  {
   public String str;
   public Object bool;

}
```

How can I do this? Unless I specify namespaces (see below), it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<object>
   <str>the type</str>
   <bool xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
       xsi:type="xs:boolean">true</bool>        
</object>
```

Comment: I have added the question here can you please once check and provide response? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78088731/7584240

Answer (score 12):

An easier way might be to use [unmarshalByDeclaredType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalByDeclaredType), since you already know the type you want to unmarshal.

By using

```
Unmarshaller.unmarshal(rootNode, MyType.class);
```

you don't need to have a namespace declaration in the XML, since you pass in the JAXBElement that has the namespace already set.

This also perfectly legal, since you are not required to reference a namespace in an XML instance, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#PO - and many clients produce XML in that fashion.

Finally got it to work. Note that you have to remove any custom namespace in the schema; here's working sample code:

The schema:

```
<xsd:schema
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="customer">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
         <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
         <xsd:element name="phone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <name>Jane Doe</name>
   <phone>08154712</phone>
</customer>
```

JAXB code:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
u.setSchema(schemaInputStream); // load your schema from File or any streamsource
Customer = u.unmarshal(new StreamSource(inputStream), clazz);  // pass in your XML as inputStream
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work with schemas where local elements have namespaces (`elementFormDefault="qualified")`. OK, the namespace (or, better the whole name) of the root element does not matter. But is it true for sub-elements? I do not think so.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I have `<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.foobar.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.foobar.com">` and a `JAXBException` is thrown.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

You can get this to work by introducing an intermediate layer to translate between `type` and `xsi:type`.  Below is example of using the StAX `StreamReaderDelegate` to do this for the JAXB unmarshal operation:

```java
package forum7184526;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLConstants;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
        xsr = new XsiTypeReader(xsr);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Spec.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Spec spec = (Spec) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

    private static class XsiTypeReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {

        public XsiTypeReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
            super(reader);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttributeNamespace(int arg0) {
            if("type".equals(getAttributeLocalName(arg0))) {
                return XMLConstants.SCHEMA_INSTANCE_URL;
            }
            return super.getAttributeNamespace(arg0);
        }

    }
}
```

---

`xsi:type` is a schema mechanism for specifying the real type of an element (similar to a cast in Java).  If you remove the namespace, you are changing the semantics of the document.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

In [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) we allow you to specify your own inheritance indicator for domain objects using `@XmlDescriminatorNode` and `@XmlDescrimatorValue`.  We currently do not offer this type of customization for data type properties:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, Blaise. I am fine with having the namespaces. But is it possible to have no namespaces in the XML (because it's going to face dev users) but keep that info with the Java class annotations, so that when jaxb parses the XML, it sees "type" and knows "aha, it is of namespace 'xsi' according Java class declaration". Same with "xs:boolean". Do you see what I'm saying? Or it is still not possible? I need this because our dev users are going to create such XML declarations and we need to unmarshal them to Java.

Comment: @Andrey - You can make this work, below is an approach you could do for the unmarshal.

Comment: Hi Blaise. The removal of a namespace for the "type" attribute worked great, THANKS A LOT!!!, but still how can I remove "xs" namespace declaration for the value of the "type" attribute - "xs:boolean". I played with overriding some of the StreamReaderDelegate methods, but no success.

Comment: @Andrey - The code in my answer just addresses the unmarshal case.  To remove the namespaces from the marshal operation you could create a wrapper for an XMLStreamWriter that intercepts and removes the relevant namespace info.  Here is a link to an answer I gave where I did something similar:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas/5722013#5722013

Comment: I am actually still talking about unmarshaling. (I corrected my initial question as well.) Basically, you suggestion helped remove the namespace declaration for "type" attribute, but I cannot figure out how to remove namespace declaration for the "type" attribute value itself. "xs:boolean" --> "boolean"

Comment: I have added the question here can you please once check and provide response? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78088731/7584240

Answer (score 3):

Based on Blaise's comments (thanks Blaise!) and my research.
Here is the solution to my problem. Do you agree with that Blaise, or you have a better way?

```java
package forum7184526;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLConstants;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
    xsr = new XsiTypeReader(xsr);

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Spec.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Spec spec = (Spec) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
}

private static class XsiTypeReader extends StreamReaderDelegate {

    public XsiTypeReader(XMLStreamReader reader) {
        super(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeNamespace(int arg0) {
        if("type".equals(getAttributeLocalName(arg0))) {
            return "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        }
        return super.getAttributeNamespace(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeValue(int arg0) {
      String n = getAttributeLocalName(arg0);
      if("type".equals(n)) {
         String v = super.getAttributeValue(arg0);
          return  "xs:"+ v;
      }
      return super.getAttributeValue(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public NamespaceContext getNamespaceContext() {
      return new MyNamespaceContext(super.getNamespaceContext());
    }
}

private static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {
  public NamespaceContext _context;
  public MyNamespaceContext(NamespaceContext c){
     _context = c;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
     return _context.getPrefixes(namespaceURI);
  }

  @Override
  public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
     return _context.getPrefix(namespaceURI);
  }

  @Override
  public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
     if("xs".equals(prefix)) {
        return  "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
     }
     return _context.getNamespaceURI(prefix);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all, here shared my solution which works for my code

i try to make it generic every namespace contain ": " i write code if any tag have ":" it will remove from xml.

This is used to skip namespace during unmarshalling using jaxb.

```
public class NamespaceFilter {

    private NamespaceFilter() {

    }

    private static final String COLON = ":";

    public static XMLReader nameSpaceFilter() throws SAXException {
        XMLReader xr = new XMLFilterImpl(XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()) {
            private boolean skipNamespace;

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
                if (qName.indexOf(COLON) > -1) {
                    skipNamespace = true;
                } else {
                    skipNamespace = false;
                    super.startElement("", localName, qName, atts);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
                if (qName.indexOf(COLON) > -1) {
                    skipNamespace = true;
                } else {
                    skipNamespace = false;
                    super.endElement("", localName, qName);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                if (!skipNamespace) {
                    super.characters(ch, start, length);
                }
            }
        };
        return xr;
    }

}
```

**for unmarshalling ,**

```
XMLReader xr = NamespaceFilter.nameSpaceFilter();
        Source src = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource("filePath"));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Result res = new StreamResult(sw);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(src, res);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tab.class);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        String done = sw.getBuffer().toString();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(done);
        Tab tab = (Tab) u.unmarshal(reader);

        System.out.println(tab);
```