# Is it possible to unmarshall an xml file that misses the namespace?

Tags: jaxb, m2e

I am using Eclipse Oxygen with m2e in order to generate Java classes from a schema.
I am able to unmarshall an xml file that adheres to that schema if the namespace matches that of the schema.

How can I unmarshall an xml file that is known to adhere to that schema but misses the namespace declaration without changing the generated xml equivalent Java source files?

The schema:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  targetNamespace="http://testJaxbUnmarshaller.ngong.eu/0_0_1" 
  xmlns:tju="http://testJaxbUnmarshaller.ngong.eu/0_0_1"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="A" type="tju:A" />
  <complexType name="A">
    <all>
      <element name="B" type="tju:B" />
    </all>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="B">
    <attribute name="name" type="string"/>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

generated A.java:

```
package eu.ngong.testJaxbUnmarshaller.jaxb;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "A", propOrder = {

})
public class A {
    @XmlElement(name = "B", required = true)
    protected B b;
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(B value) {
        this.b = value;
    }
}
```

generated B.java:

```
package eu.ngong.testJaxbUnmarshaller.jaxb;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "B")
public class B {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

The xml file that works fine:

```
<A xmlns="http://testJaxbUnmarshaller.ngong.eu/0_0_1">
  <B name="thisIsB"/>
</A>
```

The xml file leading to the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException", what I like to circumvent, telling the unmarshaller that this is to be processed as if a namespace would have been declared or telling to forget anything about namespaces.

```
<A>
  <B name="thisIsB"/>
</A>
```

The Code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
JAXBElement<A> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, A.class);
A a = (A)(je.getValue());
System.out.println("the name: " + a.getB().getName());
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184526/jaxb-how-can-i-unmarshal-xml-without-namespaces/7206666. However, I'd personally run an XSLT transformation to fix the XML prior to unmarshalling.

Comment: Thank you for that link, lexicore. It provides 2 solutions. If I got it right, the first will not work, as my example shows and as your comment there suggests.

The second is similar to your preference: manipulate the input first.

Ok, thank you for help. Now I think there is probably no such solution just by knowing more about JAXB than I do.