# Add default namespace to an element within soap body

Tags: soap, xsd, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

I have generated a web-service client (JAX-WS) and model from wsdl and xsd. I have problem with namespaces within soap body.

Lets assume we have two classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="aNamespace") class A {
   @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) Object obj;
}

@XmlRootElement(namespace="bNamespace") class B {...}
```

The object I want to send is 'a':

```
A a = new A();
a.obj = new B();
```

The service I am calling expects either of V1 or V3 requests:

```
   V1
   ...
   <soapenv:Body>
      <A xmlns="aNamespace">
         <B xmlns="bNamespace">
            <B1>...</B1>
            <B2>...</B2>
         </B>
      </A>
   </soapenv:Body>
   ...

   V3
   ...
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:A xmlns:a="aNamespace">
         <b:B xmlns:b="bNamespace">
            <b:B1>...</b:B1>
            <b:B2>...</b:B2>
         </b:B>
      </a:A>
   </soapenv:Body>
   ...
```

Trying to call the service I see following request generated:

```
   V2
   ...
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:A xmlns:a="aNamespace", xmlns:b="bNamespace">
         <b:B>
            <b:B1>...</b:B1>
            <b:B2>...</b:B2>
         </b:B>
      </a:A>
   </soapenv:Body>
   ...
```

And the service returns error.

Can I somehow set a default namespace to B(so that I will see `<B xmlns="bNamespace">`)?

Comment: Check out my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas/5722013#5722013

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you say `The service I am calling expects following model`, what does it really mean? Both XMLs reflect the same thing. The choice of namespace suffixes (or default) is by design unconstrained; a namespace aware XML processor must not care about the choice of prefixes. Is your implementation using a home grown XML parser, an old parser (can you share which one that might be), or is it a simple misunderstanding of a developer on how to deal with XML? While I understand that you might be able to do something about it, doing it for nothing is what creates ugly, legacy code.

Comment: Hey Petru, I don't have access to the implementation of web-service, so the constraint is not clear to me. I expect the service to extract B element and process it without A element information. But this is just a guess. I was able to submit variant 1 and 3, but fail on 2. Let me also mention that I am aware that all 3 should be considered the same. Assuming that is the limitation of web-service, what is the solution you have?

Comment: Blaise, thank you for possible solution, do you know how can I inject it into JAX-WS?

Comment: @Denis - I'm not sure you can, not easily anyways.  The two documents are equivalent in their namespace qualification.  Is their a real need to use the default namespace only approach?

Comment: It can also be done using third example. Default namespace is the best, otherwise I am fine with third example.

Comment: I just need to put namespace into B element, because it seems like A element namespace declarations are completely ignored on the server.

Comment: Denis, looking at the difference between what works and what doesn't reminded me of a bug in WAS 6 where the namespace attribute nodes were not correctly propagated to the child nodes - i.e. the namespace resolution mechanism was bad. However, I was on the provider side, and instead of pushing this down to my consumers to deal with it, I've worked with the vendor to fix it. Unofrtunately, I would never recommend a workaround such as the one you're thinking to apply, simply because this is not a limitation one should assume. If this service is to be invoked by other consumers, I can name...

Comment: (cont'd) a number of major XML processors that have no fine control over namespace aliasing; what would be the solution for those cases?

Comment: Will it help if I say that XSD mapping is following: "class A {@XmlAnyElement B b}"

Comment: I think there should be a solution to reduce the amount of memory required for XML by removing superfluous namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by marshaling B into DOM object. Then I put the created DOM into A.

```
B b = new B();
Document bDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class).createMarshaller().marshal(b, bDocument); 

A a = new A();
a.obj = bDocument;
```

It produces some weird result, however the web-service accepts it:

```
   ...
   <soapenv:Body>
      <a:A xmlns:a="aNamespace" xmlns:ab="bNamespace">
         <b:B xmlns:b="bNamespace">
            <b:B1>...</b:B1>
            <b:B2>...</b:B2>
         </b:B>
      </a:A>
   </soapenv:Body>
   ...
```