# stream a large String into JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a domain object in my JAXB hierarchy which must be represented as comma separated value text. Unfortunately, explicitly constructing the CSV `String` is incredibly costly so that is not an option.

I created a custom `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` that returned a `DataHandler` (as per [supported data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html#wp230880table221487)) but that always writes the data out in BASE64... but I have a legacy API to preserve that expects the ASCII string in there. Changing the MIME of the `DataHandler` doesn't change the encoding, but it would impact the XSD's definition of the object contained within.

**Is there any way to setup `DataHandler` (or any other supported Java type) to return the un-encoded `String` from a streaming input?**

I also considered returning an `Object` (which was really a `CharacterData`) but that needs to implement `public String getData()`... requiring me to explicitly construct the `String` that I'm trying to stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case no one comes up with `DataHanler`-related solution... The following is just an alternative idea for a "work-around" which does not involve `DataHandler`. It requires access to the marshaller.

- Modify your XML type adapter to not return the content but a kind of short address to get hold of the streaming data (e.g. a file name).
- Define a XMLStreamWriter wrapper like here: [JAXB marshalling XMPP stanzas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas). Overwrite the `writeStartElement` and `writeCharacters` to intercept the `startElement` invocation of the CSV element and the immediately following `writeCharacters`.
- The data passed to that specific invocation of `writeCharacters` will be the address to get hold of the streaming data. Stream it in chunks to the wrapped XMLStreamWriter's writeCharacters.

Comment: this looks like it could work! I'll give it a try and respond if it does (probably a week).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why explicitly constructing the CSV string (using StringBuilder) would be more costly than using JAXB builtins.

If the performance is your limiting factor, then I think you should consider creating custom serializers (StringBuilder based, for example) and SAX handlers to parse the XML.

If you have the luxury of changing the protocol, then you might want to check out [Grizzly framework](https://grizzly.java.net/), [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/gettingstartedjava.html) and [Google ProtoBuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) - there's quite a bit more maintenance with them, but if you are going after performance then these should be faster.

As always, you should do A/B performance tests using both methods before setting anything into stone ;)

Back to the original topic, here's an example on how to use custom adapters:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Example
{
    public String serialize( DataObject d ) throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext.newInstance(DataObject.class).createMarshaller().marshal(d, buffer);
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSerialize( ) throws JAXBException {
        String expected = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><dataObject>"
                          + "<FirstField>field1 content with special characters &amp;&lt;&gt;'\"</FirstField>"
                          + "<Second>&lt;!CDATA[[ &lt;!-- now we're just nasty --&gt; ]]&gt;</Second>"
                          + "<Custom>a,b,c</Custom></dataObject>";

        assertEquals(expected, serialize(new DataObject()).replaceAll("(\r)?\n(\r)?", "\n"));
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
class DataObject
{
    @XmlElement( name = "FirstField" )
    private final String field1 = "field1 content with special characters &<>'\"";

    @XmlElement( name = "Second" )
    private final String field2 = "<!CDATA[[ <!-- now we're just nasty --> ]]>";

    @XmlElement( name = "Custom" )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( value = CustomAdapter.class )
    // you can move this over the type
    private final CustomType type = new CustomType("a", "b", "c");
}

@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
class CustomType
{
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
    private final String c;

    public CustomType( String a, String b, String c ) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getA( ) {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB( ) {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC( ) {
        return c;
    }
}

class CustomAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, CustomType>
{
    @Override
    public String marshal( CustomType v ) throws Exception {
        return String.format("%s,%s,%s", v.getA(), v.getB(), v.getC());
    }

    @Override
    /** Please don't use this in PROD :> */
    public CustomType unmarshal( String v ) throws Exception {
        String[] split = v.split(",");
        return new CustomType(split[ 0 ], split[ 1 ], split[ 2 ]);
    }
}
```

This should get you going, unless I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: `buffer.toString()` => `OutOfMemoryError`. That's the problem in a nutshell :-) (actually, we don't OOM, but imagine serving a lot of these requests at the same time and imagine how the GC copes under that kind of load. We've profiled it, it's a killer, and streaming is the solution.)

Comment: Oooh, so that's the problem.

I guess you could try to use output stream instead of string writer while marshaling, but that could blow up too, depending on implementation details.

The other thing is switching to completely streaming api - here are some examples http://java.dzone.com/articles/xml-unmarshalling-benchmark ("JAXB + STax" section), but if the CSV string itself is the problem, then I'm afraid you've hit a corner case. 

Anyway, if I find something interesting, I'll post it here.

Comment: exactly, I'm trying to get to a point where I can pass a streamable object to JAXB (i.e. construct the CSV on the fly from smaller objects). The problem I came up against is that the only streamable object in JAXB streams into a base64 and I need ASCII. The suggestion above to provide a custom intercepting XMLStreamWriter sounds good, but keen to hear any other approaches you might have.