# JAXB marshalling: change element which should declare a namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

When using JAXB marshalling, do I have an **influence** on **which element** a namespace/namespace prefix will be **declared**?

Currently, all namespace prefixes are declared at the root element, but due to strange limitations of the system which processes my XML I need to declare them at child elements (which would still result in a valid xml document).

A similar, but not identical request has been made to the [official jaxb issue tracker and declined by a developer](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-103?focusedCommentId=64411&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_64411) back in 2006. I'd like to know if this situation changed in the meanwhile or if some workarounds exist.

Any help is appreciated.

***Example:***

JAXB marshalling creates the following XML:

```
<outer xmlns:ns1="http://mydomain">
  <inner>
     <ns1:data/>
  </inner>
</outer>
```

While I need to have something like
(`ns1` prefix is **not** declared at the root element):

```
<outer>
  <inner xmlns:ns1="http://mydomain">
     <ns1:data/>
  </inner>
</outer>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of expected XML please?

Comment: You might find this useful. https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/vendorProperties.html. Check the documentation for the method `getPreDeclaredNamespaceUris()`.

Comment: Thanks, however this method is useful for the inverse problem: jaxb 1.0, which worked more or less like I need it to - declared the namespace on the element which required it first. This method can then be used to set the namespace declarations at the root element instead.

Comment: What happens if you return an empty array from the method?

Comment: It would change nothing, because this is already happening in the default implementation which gets used (the concrete implementation is located here:  com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.output.NamespaceContextImpl.defaultNamespacePrefixMapper ) - this class extends the class you pointed to (and where you can see that an empty list is already being returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) does not provide a means to control where namespace declarations occur. JAXB providers tend to put the namespaces on the root element (for performance reasons), but they are not required to.

Below is a link to an answer I gave to a similar question where `XMLStreamWriter` is extended to control when the namespace declarations get reported.

- [JAXB marshalling XMPP stanzas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas/5722013#5722013)

Comment: Although I'm considering the proposed XMLStreamWriter way as a workaround only, it seems to be the only compatible way to solve my problem - thanks.