# Namespace on each field JAXB

Tags: xml, groovy, jaxb

I'm sitting here with JAXB which I have very little experience with (i'm really a .NET guy). But i'm suppose to translate a system from .NET to groovy, for at customer.

Anyway. here is the issue. I have a HUGE xml file, which in the old system would have xml namespaces on each xml tag like this:

```
<RapportV4Type xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:4">
    <RapportResume xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:resume:1">
        <RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst></RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst></RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst></RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <RapportResumeTekst></RapportResumeTekst>
                <RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </Rapportvalgmulighed>
        </RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
    </RapportResume>
    <RapportstatusV2 xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:2">
        <RapportstatusV2Kode></RapportstatusV2Kode>
    </RapportstatusV2>
    <GennemfoertDato xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></GennemfoertDato>
    <GenbestillingerTilbageKvantitet xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></GenbestillingerTilbageKvantitet>
    <GenbestillingsperiodesOphoerDato xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></GenbestillingsperiodesOphoerDato>
    <RapportbestillingV3 xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:3">
        <RapportBestillingIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportBestillingIdentifikator>
        <RapportbestillingDatoV2 xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:2"></RapportbestillingDatoV2>
        <EjendomIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></EjendomIdentifikator>
        <KommuneIdentifikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></KommuneIdentifikator>
        <RapportvalgmulighedValgSamling xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1">
            <RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator></RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator>
            <RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator></RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator>
            <RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator></RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator>
            <RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator></RapportvalgmulighedValgIdentifikator>
        </RapportvalgmulighedValgSamling>
        <AdviseringsAdresse xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1">
            <EmailAdresseIdentifikator></EmailAdresseIdentifikator>
            <TelefonNummerIdentifikator></TelefonNummerIdentifikator>
        </AdviseringsAdresse>
        <FuldmagtIndhentetIndikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></FuldmagtIndhentetIndikator>
        <RapportFortroligIndikator xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1"></RapportFortroligIndikator>
    </RapportbestillingV3>
```

The issue is that with the following code:

```
static <T> Element serializeGenericObjectToXmlTypeElement(T object, Class<T> genericType, boolean removeDeclaration = false) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(genericType)
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller()

        if (removeDeclaration) {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true)
        }

        Writer writer = new StringWriter()
        marshaller.marshal(object, writer)
        def xmlString = writer.toString()
        def stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString)
        def builder = new SAXBuilder()
        def doc = builder.build(stringReader)
        def elem = doc.getRootElement()
        return elem
    }
```

The namespaces are move to the root element, and then every xml tag, gets a prefix. Like this:

```
<RapportV4Type xmlns="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:4" xmlns:ns6="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:1" xmlns:ns5="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:1" xmlns:ns7="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:metadata:2" xmlns:ns2="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:2" xmlns:ns4="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:resume:1" xmlns:ns3="urn:oio:ebst:diadem:3">
    <ns4:RapportResume>
        <ns4:RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
            <ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <ns4:RapportResumeTekst></ns4:RapportResumeTekst>
                <ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator></ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <ns4:RapportResumeTekst></ns4:RapportResumeTekst>
                <ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator></ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <ns4:RapportResumeTekst></ns4:RapportResumeTekst>
                <ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator></ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
            <ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
                <ns4:RapportResumeTekst></ns4:RapportResumeTekst>
                <ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator></ns5:RapportvalgmulighedIdentifikator>
            </ns4:Rapportvalgmulighed>
        </ns4:RapportvalgmulighedSamling>
```

All of my classe are generated from XSD files (The classes that needs to be serialized and deserialized). It works fine in the .NET solution with the files. But with JAXB it gives this structure.

I have tried to declare root elements with namespaces in each of the classes, but that doesn't do anything. I also tried the accepted answer from here: [JAXB marshalling XMPP stanzas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720501/jaxb-marshalling-xmpp-stanzas) But that didn't work either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The two XML docs are supposed to be equivalent. The second one using namespace prefixes is a better form because it avoids all the awkward/redundant repetitions of namespace declaration of the first one. It should not make a difference for XML libraries, they should understand namespace prefixes.

Comment: I know that the output most likely is best practice. But the internal system is setup in a way, that we need the namespaces on the individual elements. We don't have the time to change how it works when we translate it. The system has to be done by december (we didn't built the original system)